# Don't show App Picker if current activity can handle NFC

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm writing a handful of NFC-capable apps for work.
I've got two of them on my tablet right now, and they are set to launch if an NFC tag is detected and they're not already open. So since I have two of them on the same device now I get an App Picker dialog. This is great.

What I would like is to make it so that if one of the apps is already open, that when the NFC tag is detected it doesn't show the app picker, but just uses the current activity to handle the NFC intent. How possible is this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the foreground activity is using [`enableForegroundDispatch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%5B%5D%29), it will take precedence over anything else registered in the manifest for the tag.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NFC/URLTagger) that demonstrates the use of `enableForegroundDispatch()`, to write text shared from another app (e.g., URL from the Browser) to an NFC tag.

Comment: Thanks a million. I'm getting a NullPointerException from onResume though, any idea why?

Comment: @Nick: Um, because something is `null`? :-) Are you referring to your code or mine?

Comment: Haha, technically both because I copied some of your relevant code into my code. All I added was an SDK check: `IntentFilter discovery=new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
  IntentFilter[] tagFilters=new IntentFilter[] { discovery };
  Intent i=new Intent(this, getClass())
  .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
   mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pi, tagFilters, null);
  }`

Comment: @Nick: Which line is the one with the `NullPointerException`? Did you run my sample verbatim to see if it was behaving for you?

Comment: Oh, whoops, I never initialized my NFC adapter. Now it never gets to my NFC handling code, though. I get a message in the LogCat saying "startActivity called from non-Activity context"

Comment: @Nick: Are you implementing `onNewIntent()`, per the example? Can I convince you into buying [a rather nice book](http://commonsware.com/Android/) that covers all of this in detail? :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14359/discussion-between-nick-and-commonsware)